# For a git submodule, which commit will be cloned if no version is specified in .gitmodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Does git follow a certain set of rules when the `.gitmodules` file only specifies `path` and `url` for a submodule?

Comment: Generally, the commit to be cloned is controlled by the `commit` entries in the parent repository, not by the contents of the `.gitmodules` file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/7976758